# How to make my codigniter url seo friendly

Tags: codeigniter, url, seo

How to make my codigniter url seo friendly.

this is my url

http://localhost/picker2/web/search?category=doctor

i want url like this

http://localhost/picker2/web/search/doctor/

Comment: This has been asked a few times I am sure if you look on stack overflow you will find it.

Answer (score 1):

read this article [www.askaboutphp.com/58/codeigniter-mixing-segment-based-url-with-querystrings.html](http://www.askaboutphp.com/58/codeigniter-mixing-segment-based-url-with-querystrings.html)

to create url like this : http://heloo.com/article/codeigniter-based-url
add this code in routes.php

```
$route['article/(:any)'] = "article/readmore/$1";
```

description :

1. article : class name
2. readmore : method from class article
3. $1 : get value from uri segment 2 value

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have two options

1) Using Routes (this one already denyptw discussed right ?)

2) use the URL Helper url_title function

Note : You can use Parameter instead of query string

http://localhost/picker2/web/search?category=doctor

http://localhost/picker2/web/search/doctor/

web controller , search function , doctor parameter

example :

```
class Web extends CI_Controller
{

public function search($value)
{

  //use this $value in your searching logic 

}



}
```

You need Example of URL Helper

check this link [Codeigniter URL: How to display id and article title in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683820/codeigniter-url-how-to-display-id-and-article-title-in-the-url)

Answer (score 0):

1. you can do this using [routes](http://www.jamesstoddern.net/seo-friendly-urls-in-codeigniter-the-challenge.html).([Elislab](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/urls.html))
2. as a simple trick.(Using Controllers)

   - each and every page create a controller. (ex: if contact create `contact` controller, if product create `product` controller.) So each and every link will be look like(if you click product) `www.example.com/product`,(if you click contact) `www.example.com/contact`.
   - If you want something to do with your product then write that method inside the product controller.(ex if you create cart then URL show `www.example.com/product/cart` )